# What would cause the following error: 'Eject "Apple SSD - Data" before disconnecting or turning it off'

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, eject

I just saw the message below on my 2015 MacBook Pro running macOS 12.2.1.  It seems weird for macOS to be complaining about ejecting an internal SSD that I could never actually eject.

What could cause this? Is there anything that I need to do to fix it or diagnose it?

[image]

I have no external drives hardwired to this laptop, if it matters.

I saw this after unlocking my Mac. Right before that, I woke it up by typing on my external keyboard. This laptop is usually docked and connected to KVM by an [IOGEAR GCS62DP](https://www.iogear.com/product/GCS62DP/) KVM switch.

Here's output from `diskutil list`:

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         1.0 TB     disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +1.0 TB     disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD - Data⁩        396.2 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 718.9 MB   disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.6 GB     disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      7.5 GB     disk1s4
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨APPLE SSD⁩               15.8 GB    disk1s5
   6:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.8 GB    disk1s5s1

/dev/disk2 (disk image):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk3⁩         2.0 TB     disk2s2

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk3
                                 Physical Store disk2s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Time Machine Backups⁩    543.1 GB   disk3s1
```

Comment: It is weird indeed... Could you add the output of `diskutil list` to your question? Has this happened once or more often? Do you recall what you were working on when this happened (installing an app, running a script, unmounting a flash drive)?

Comment: @jaume I updated the question with additional info Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for updating the question. It seems your internal disk is called `⁨Macintosh HD - Data` (can you confirm with a Disk Utility screenshot?), so the question is: what is `Apple SSD - Data`? Could it be that you had an old Mac SSD disk connected to your dock?

Comment: @jaume Oops, I ran `diskutil list` on the wrong laptop. I have two of the same model, one that's always docked (the one where I saw this error message popup) and another that's only docked sometimes. I mistakenly ran `diskutil list` on the not-always-docked one. I edited the question to show output from the correct laptop, which does show "Apple SSD - Data" as expected.

Comment: Well, the mystery about what caused the notification to show up is not yet solved, but it is now clear that `Apple SSD - Data` is indeed an internal SSD partition, thanks for updating your question.

Answer (score 0):

My 2021 M1 MacBook Pro is doing this. When I first open it up in the morning, I get the alert shown, but for the disk "Data". Thank you @jaume for pointing out diskutil list. Here is the relevant part of mine:

```
/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +2.0 TB     disk3
                             Physical Store disk0s2
1:                APFS Volume ⁨Macintosh HD⁩            15.4 GB    disk3s1
2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk3s1s1
3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 596.1 MB   disk3s2
4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                827.2 MB   disk3s3
5:                APFS Volume ⁨Data⁩                    85.4 GB    disk3s5
6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      20.5 KB    disk3s6
```

So it would appear that disk "Data" is -- all my data! Somehow the system thinks it has to remount the internal SSD, or that rather important part of it.